# Posting comment on facebook group post with api?

Tags: javascript, php

Does the facebook allow users to post comments on any public page with their API?

What i am trying to do i post comments from multiple accounts on page post, but cant seem to find anything related for that?

Comment: I'm afraid this is the wrong forum for your question. I'm sure there is a forum about facebook's api somewhere.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is something that can you can find the answer to [with a quick google search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/). Your app needs to be approved first by facebook to use the group api endpoints. May I ask what's the purpose of creating something that posts from many different accounts?